# I want to send cyrillic letter to mysqli database with php

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, utf-8

In my .html document where the form is i have

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

in the .php file where i connect to the database i tried with

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');   
// and 
// <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

and this:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

The database rows are with Collation: `utf8_unicode_ci`

Comment: Try replacing the special characters with ansi as shown in the following website: http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ansi.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through#

Comment: My issue is that when i send the cyrillic letters to the database i get something like this -> Ð˜Ð·Ð±ÐµÑ€ÐµÑ‚ and not the letters

Answer (score 0):

You were hoping for something like `Избере`?  You have Mojibake.  Probably this is what happened:

- The bytes you have in the client are correctly encoded in utf8 (good).
- You connected with `SET NAMES latin1` (or `set_charset('latin1')` or ...), probably by default.  (It should have been `utf8`.)
- The column in the tables may or may not have been `CHARACTER SET utf8`, but it should have been that.

If you need to **fix the data** it takes a "2-step ALTER", something like

```
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARBINARY(...) ...;
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(...) ... CHARACTER SET utf8 ...;
```

where the lengths are big enough and the other "..." have whatever else (`NOT NULL`, etc) was already on the column.

Unfortunately, if you have a lot of columns to work with, it will take a lot of ALTERs.  You can (should) `MODIFY` all the necessary columns to `VARBINARY` for a single table in a pair of `ALTERs`.